# Change tab color, based on data in column

Tags: excel, colors, tabs

How can I change the color of a tab in excel 2010, based on the data in Column D?  ie... if a cell in column D contains "F" or "f", then change the tab to red, then if a cell in column D contains "PWE" or "pwe", then change the tab to yellow, then if "P" or "p" change to green, if none of those, then don't change the tab color.  Help... Thanks!!

```
Sub tabby()

    If Range("D:D").Text = "F" Or "f" Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Tab.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
    ElseIf Range("D:D").Text = "PWE" Or "pwe" Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Tab.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
    ElseIf Range("D:D").Text = "P" Or "p" Then
        ActiveWorkbook.Tab.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
    Else
        ActiveWorkbook.Tab.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you mean by `If Range("D:D").Text = "F" Or "f" Then`. Though the base intention can be inferred, you generally would not determine if an *F* existed anywhere in column D. Was there a single cell (or smaller cell range) that would be more appropriate?

Comment: Essentially, I'm trying to determine if a manual test script is a failure at a glance.  So if there is an "F" (text) in any cell within column D, then the test procedure is a failure and the tab should change to the color Red.  I have a range of 10 test scripts in this particular Workbook, and I want to open it after Test Execution, and glance at all of the tabs to determine with Test should be re-run or analyzed....  hope this helps further..

Answer (score 1):

I've used the native worksheet [COUNTIF function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIF-function-a8b3d1c2-309b-4e44-9047-e1746e90e55c) to determine if the terms are found in column D and converted the `If... ElseIf ... ElseIf ...` to a `Select Case`. The search terms are in an array that get looped through.

```
Sub tabby()
    Dim w As Long, v As Long, vTERMs As Variant
    vTERMs = Array("f", "pwe", "p")
    For w = 1 To Sheets.Count
        With Sheets(w)
            For v = LBound(vTERMs) To UBound(vTERMs)
                If CBool(Application.CountIf(.Columns(4), vTERMs(v))) Then
                    Select Case v
                        Case 0
                            .Tab.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
                        Case 1
                            .Tab.Color = RGB(255, 255, 0)
                        Case 2
                            .Tab.Color = RGB(0, 255, 0)
                    End Select
                    Exit For
                Else
                    .Tab.Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                End If
            Next v
        End With
    Next w
End Sub
```

Note that the order of the terms is important. If one term is found, the loop is exited so priority terms to search for should be first. I've used the order that you had in your sample code for the above.

Comment: Btw, to remove the color from a tab the `.Color` should be set to `xlAutomatic` (e.g. -4105), not `RGB(0, 0, 0)`. I used your code's color setting in my code but it contradicts your description. `RGB(0, 0, 0)` sets a tab black.